# reference for reading Schoen Yau positive mass theorem proof II

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am trying to read the paper by Schoen and Yau, Proof of the Positive Mass Theorem II. The notation is very different from what I am familiar with (basically Robert Wald's book on general relativity). In particular, they use Cartan's moving frame method and their structure equation is of different sign from what I have seen. Can anyone point me to a differential geometry reference that is of same notation as Schoen&Yau paper?

Any references on PDE or related toward understanding Schoen-Yau paper is also greatly appreciated!

Just in case it would be helpful to anyone else. For Schoen and Yau 1979 proof, Fernado Marques did a very helpful lecture covering it (recording available at https://video-archive.fields.utoronto.ca/list/event/1367) and also his lecture note ([https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rcabral/pdfs/minimalsurfaces.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ercabral/pdfs/minimalsurfaces.pdf)).

Thanks!

Comment: I think Dan Lee's _Geometric Relativity_ book (AMS GTM201) has an entire chapter (chapter 8) devoted to the space-time PMT. I don't know how closely it follows Schoen and Yau's original proof, as Dan has also worked on a more modern version recently so that may have influenced his writing. (Certainly for the Riemannian PMT Dan "cheats"  by using Lohkamp's reduction so did not fully follow Schoen and Yau I.)

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted. Thank you @WillieWong

Answer (score 3):

Already found one that might be helpful so I share it here, notes for a short course by Schoen at Tsinghua unversity, [https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~zhou/Math_GR_2012.pdf](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ezhou/Math_GR_2012.pdf)

Also, Yau's own explanation in a lecture at Harvard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCIpxab8WDc&list=PL5ahlY3eFvHYrtDc_8Y-iO2uOQjz8sslC&index=3

Thanks to Willie Wong for pointing out Dan Lee's Geometric Relativity book, which gives the most up-to-date and complete summary on PMT proof. (Still Schoen's own lecture note is very helpful for building intuition about Jang's equation.)